# Safely remove an Android Activity

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity, eclipse-adt

We all know how easily and safely to create a new `Activity`. Now I want to know how to remove an `Activity` from my project safely.

I've created some activity in my project and feel that they are now needless and I want to delete them. But if I delete manually these files:

1. The activity's XML file in the `/layout` folder
2. The activity's Java file in the `/src` folder
3. The `<activity></activity>` portion from the manifest file

Then,

- Will no other data related that activity stays in my project? What are those?
- Is there any simple removal procedure like creating an activity in Eclipse?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

I found my answer. To remove an activity, let the name of the activity is `activity`:

1. Remove the `activity.java` file from `src` folder (`java/your.package.name` folder for AndroidStudio)
2. Remove the `activity.xml` file from `layouts` folder (`layout` folder for AndroidStudio)
3. Remove the `activity.xml` file from `res/menu` folder (this is an optional folder)
4. Remove the `<activity></activity>` block of the activity from the `manifest` file
5. If the `<activity>` block in the `manifest` file has a reference (usually in `android:label` tag) remove the referenced value (usually from `values/strings.xml`).

According to answers from @**ojonugwa ochalifu** and @**Md Tarik Mahmud** you should also right click on app folder then `Refractor -> Remove Unused Resources`

Comment: Hi, Where do you find the menu folder?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but it seems like the manifest file activity is automatically removed when the layout activity.xml is deleted

Answer (score 24):

Just do it in a two steps in Android Studio.

1. Delete the Activity's Java file: YourActivity.java
2. Select **app** from the Project-Browser in Left Panel. Click **Refactor** from menu, click **Remove Unused Resources**.

You are done.

Comment: And then right click on ./app -> refactor -> Remove unused resources

Answer (score 7):

I don't think there is any procedure to delete an activity at once from everywhere.

Delete the entry from manifest first. Then delete the Activity class file. Once class file is deleted you will start getting errors where it is used. Look into each error separately and resolve them.

Answer (score 4):

And the title string in res/values/xml/strings.xml

Comment: This should really have been a comment to Rohit5k2's answer and not a separate answer, but thank you for your contribution.

Answer (score 3):

Just to make sure you have deleted everything after following @CoolBrain's answer, do:

```
Refractor -> Remove Unused Resources
```

This will remove residues of that activity you aren't sure you've deleted. Note however that this operation removes unused drawables, and views also

Answer (score 2):

Right click on each of the file associated with the activity (in Android View), select  refactor, then select safe delete. This will also tell you if there are any use (of that file) which makes it not safe to delete.

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer. To remove an activity, let the name of the activity is activity:

Remove the `activity.java` file from src folder (`java/your.package.name` folder for AndroidStudio)
Remove the `activity.xml` file from `layouts` folder (layout folder for AndroidStudio)
Remove the `activity.xml` file from `res/menu` folder (this is an optional folder)
Remove the `<activity></activity>` block of the activity from the `manifest` file
If the `<activity>` block in the `manifest` file has a reference (usually in `android:label` tag) remove the referenced value (usually from `values/strings.xml`).
According to answers from @ojonugwa ochalifu and @Md Tarik Mahmud you should also right click on app folder then `Refractor -> Remove Unused Resources`

Thanks to @A. K. M. Tariqul Islam for answare.

Comment: What new information does your answer contain that the others didn't?